# I can import tensorflow on python terminal but if i tried to run my py file i cant

Tags: python, tensorflow, raspberry-pi

When i use python in terminal ;

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python
Python 3.7.3 (default, Dec 20 2019, 18:57:59) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
2020-07-26 12:52:03.075590: E tensorflow/core/platform/hadoop/hadoop_file_system.cc:132] HadoopFileSystem load error: libhdfs.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>>>
```

But i tried run my py file

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo python /home/pi/tfdeneme.py
pygame 1.9.4.post1
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/tfdeneme.py", line 17, in <module>
    import tensorflow
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

Im using tensorflow 2.2.0 on my windows machine, on raspberry pi tensorflow version =

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python
Python 3.7.3 (default, Dec 20 2019, 18:57:59) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
2020-07-26 12:53:49.504578: E tensorflow/core/platform/hadoop/hadoop_file_system.cc:132] HadoopFileSystem load error: libhdfs.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>>> tf.__version__
'1.14.0'
```

Whay should i do to run my py file ?

Answer (score 0):

I was having issues with TF 2.2.0 with python 3.7 and hence downgraded to python 3.6 and now it seems to be working. Please note i am on a Mac though